# Maintain and create multiple resource Auroradb's Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-aurora, terragrunt

I would like to find a way how to create more aurora db without going to destroy the ones already created. In general I use an aurora module to create my resource. Now I figured that for existing resources to be created and maintained I use a for_each or a count.

The result of both is that already existing resources are destroyed and recreated. How can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If you added a `for_each` to a resource that already existed, you will need to do something like `terraform state rm` + `terraform import` to get the Terrafomr state up to date.

Comment: Sorry I ask because I'm inexperienced why should I do terraform state rm + terraform import?

Comment: And then I should just write terraform state rm and after terraform import without specifying anything else?

Comment: You obviously need to look up those commands and pass them all the appropriate parameters so that they will actually work. Without seeing your code and your `terraform plan` output I can't really tell you exactly what to put there.